# Computing new variable of nominal and scale z scores variables

Tags: categorical-data, computational-statistics, variable

I'm analyzing a set of data where participants' reaction time and number of errors made during the task were measured. As there were two trials (where same data was measured) I was thinking I could compute new variable of standardized scores for Znumber_of_errors_1 + Zreaction_time_1 and analogically for the second trial to get an idea of how hard the task was in both trials.

My question is: can those two (namely nominal variable and scale variable) be computed into one? If so, is adding them a good way to go?

Thank you, 
Eva

Answer (score 0):

First, number of errors is a count variable and isn't nominal (count variables don't fit perfectly into the nominal, ordinal, interval, ratio framework).

Second if you add a count to a z score, what will you get? Will it be useful? Which one will get more emphasis?

If you want the two variables (count and z score) to have relatively equal influence on the score, then you could use the geometric mean of the two numbers. But whether you want them to have equal influence is up to you.